# Why do objects not automatically inherit from Object in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

(Sorry if this is a duplicate, googling this is really hard without getting unrelated results, lol)

So in TS there's the `object` primitive type and the [`Object` interface type](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/main/src/lib/es5.d.ts#LL105-L110C24) (notice the capitalisation). The `Object` interface defines common object methods like `valueOf` and `toString`, and enables type checking on this, so this doesn't compile:

###### [Open TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=8&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/DYUwLgBAxg9grgOzCAThAvBA3gNwIbBwgBcEAzADQRgwDKYKAlggOakAGA2rIsigLrsAvhADOeMI1EAzRiFEQA8gCMAViChgA3ACgA9HogwUO0JB5JUAJlIr1mjNnyES5KjXpNWHbvEsDhfUNjCAB3RjAACwhmPmk8KHliHVjUeMSIAGE-PisIEAAPZAQAEwU7DUgsHQhaiGciUgQ4AFtlVF066joGZjYxXtZdISA)

```
let counter = {value: 3, /* error */ toString: `[counter]`} satisfies Object;
// or
let counter2: Object = {value: 3, /* error */ toString: `[counter]`}
// or with interfaces:
interface /* error */ Counter2 extends Object {
    value: number;
    toString: string;
}
```

This (rightfully so) gives me this error:

> (method) Object.toString(): string
> Error: Type 'string' is not assignable to type '() => string'.(2322)

But if I remove the explicit inheritance from the `Object` interface (and therefore only inherits from the `object` primitive, which has zero properties) it **compiles**, but throws a **runtime error** because the type of toString is incorrect:

###### [Open TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEoPSrQYwGwJawNagE4FcB2oAuA9qAM4Cmp+AFhaeugegFCPyl5wE562gC8oAbwBuAQ3iZSALlABmADT4CAZTzpE2AObSABgG1YnbN3QBdbQF8A3IxCgGLNhy60ATH0GjxU2QsIq1mjr6hsZm5jZgDKAA7oh4lKDqxgBmIrCkxJKMSbSp6aAAwiGugozg4J4S0tiYALYARrTW5Yr+6lokqu3W4Q7sxKruAEQAKtR29QBWpLB4xKAi6BRDoADUTkY86ysi2AAmoCvrBs7oLkA)

```
let counter = {value: 3, toString: `[counter]`};
// or
let counter2 = {value: 3, toString: `[counter]`}
// or with interfaces:
interface Counter2 {
    value: number;
    toString: string;
}

let str = "The objects are " + counter + " and " + counter2
```

**Why is this allowed?** This seems like an oversight, or is there any reason for this? An Object should inherit from `Object.prototype`, and it does so at runtime, so why is this not the default in TS?

Comment: For one thing, you should not be using `Object` as a type.

Comment: `extends Object` should be: `extends Object.prototype`

Comment: I'd say the compiler should definitely let you write `let x = {toString: ""}` if you want to, but possibly it should complain when you try to use it somewhere that treats `toString` as a `string`-returning method, such as `"" + x`.  The fact that it doesn't do this seems like a missing TS feature, not some kind of major bug or oversight (since we can presume this happens quite infrequently).

Comment: @jcalz and then there's https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/no-base-to-string and similar linter rules

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why is this allowed?

Simply put, because you would be hard-pressed to misuse it. As you identified in your first code snippet, you cannot extend from `Object` if your new interface violates the contract of `Object`.

In that same way, you will not be able to use your interface in places where the `Object` interface is expected.

```
let counter2 = {value: 3, toString: `[counter]`}

function callToStringOnMe(obj: Object) {
    return obj.toString();
}

// Error, as expected: Types of property 'toString' are incompatible.
callToStringOnMe(counter2);
```

Comment: Well, it's easy to accidentally use `counter2` with built-in operations that misuse it, like writing `"" + counter2`, (as shown in OP's question), but presumably this happens infrequently enough that it's not worth it to try to account for.